# Share SMB Server Through SFTP

Tags: sftp, smb

I have files stored on a NAS that I would like to access from the internet, but I know that forwarding a port running normal smb or ftp is a bad idea. I’m hoping to be able to use my Linux machine to mount the smb share, and then share that via sftp which I can port forward. Is this possible? I would just move the hard drive from the NAS to the Linux computer but there aren’t enough available SATA Ports.

Thank you for your time,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

the only safe way is not to use a password and setup public keys for your sftp connection to the outside world:

```
ssh-keygen
```

If you don't set a password, then you can script it to auto-start. You can also use a password to encrypt your private keys. You'd then want to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to only allow login with the keys not the password.

You should see something like below. The private key should never leave your machine.

```
tom@jb:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/tom/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/tom/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /home/tom/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:3f88MO3hUf4DvGFASPjuWEmoTwCGFsw3s+xGJgjtFck tom@jb
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|ooo..o  o..      |
|.=.*E  . . .     |
|+.+.=   o .      |
|...= . . + o    .|
|  =   o S o + ...|
|   o . . +   O +.|
|  .   o +   . X +|
|       o .   . B.|
|                =|
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

The public key should be added to your server's authorized keys file:

```
cat /home/tom/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys # roughly speaking
```

Don't ask me how you plan to get the pub keys on their in the first place though! THis is the text that looks like;

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQC+ybhOrgg7SBbbMho75R2DsAnFNjHGZGEa2i2PhNM2mGAOY/7GRGhEQsUuGHyciuvSld7m+HVTEemXQszAc9B0/ElO/wuz1+i/elSpi6dbMuzqihZE9SFik8GQzf8BxrgsU1av/OazwagLUPWm2Y4XGxYZrfolRSnhYiJ3htB8G6TH6yemX9jZ6btxTlUlCtkmgR0hTA8iZzPwTAr/g9TckBee9nbq9amcVO2ff+t+ and this is only the pub key of a 4096 bit pair remember MZFF8PxDFQH70qWcrb2XSlUvhsfCGZxTQqLWON749rLXQSPSbW8nFA2Lz1mRJ++NnChvPcODBgVfBd+E59LBSsD9JLcBrWJj5IBpTBu9znNR3QaMYukrQ0Cnpa01+6ZwmEilhQBZg/xtrJxGK8vq8SQamtWWNzY5Bm0atsbdazXX8j7AUogMNHiXICIrVky6jf4E5tH57dQeHeUTWgU5Ql3q6yyfKh/Q1HJMdvIlS58cYE5Xc= tom@jb
```

Your sshd server may need to listen on the wide-open to the internet 0.0.0.0 instead of say 127.0.0.1 (only you) or maybe 192.168.1.69 for a LAN. THen open port 22 on your firewall to your host 192.168.1.69 etc. which If you need the path of your SMB or SFTP shares from inside the ssh tunnel, try dragging and dropping the icon for the folder in question to reveal a path like:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=moderna.local/Users/tom/ALLYOURBASE
```

This is how I get on to some old HFS+ and APFS macOS format disks with read/write. Good solution to the read-only mount issue there. This remote-mounted network share is available via /run/ after using sftp to get in (ftp over ssh).

I find sshfs to be preferred over samba - but is a little more CPU intense, so if a big job maybe will use samba but mounting / at /mnt/sshs covers my needs.

**Mount-Free WAN Wildcard Option**
Something like `ssh -L 10.10.10.22:445:192.168.1.69:445` (or perhaps with -R I often get the order wrong, maybe try `ssh -R *:445:192.168.1.69:445`)

With the * now everyone on the remote LAN can sort-of access that machine if they hit it like \192.168.1.69\MyDerkaments or maybe smb:\10.10.10.22\DerkaDerkaShare etc when the tunnel is up your linxuxbox can forward SYNs through to the NAS. Bakala.

Hope you have a firewall there I would not advise opening 445 to the full flaming heat of the interweb.

You can use ssh to send your NAS port 445 as a remote listening socket: making it available inside a remote LAN say pretty cool. If it doesn't mind responding to some different subnets.

nmap your nas, look for  port 445, say it's called derka_muhamed_nas you'd:

```
root@putin:/# nmap derka_muhamed_nas
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-11-17 05:47 NZDT
Nmap scan report for naztynasofderkaderka (10.0.0.60)
Host is up (0.00068s latency).
rDNS record for 10.0.0.60: derka_muhamed_nas

PORT      STATE SERVICE
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds   <---  Samba run on port 445 yeah?
```

not safe for net though, if you tunnel it, only one machine can be the host, cos smb has to be on 445 unlike cooler protocols like ssh that can run on any port.